# How to populate variables in href

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm currently pulling variables from my query string using this:

```
function getUrlVars()
{
  var vars = [], hash;
  var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
  for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
  {
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
  }
  return vars;
}

var s1 = getUrlVars()["s1"];
var s2 = getUrlVars()["s2"];
var s3 = getUrlVars()["s3"];
```

Now, I know that that was properly done.

The issue I'm having is this: I need to populate those variables inside my code after the corresponding parameters, but I don't know how.

```
<body>
  <div id="main">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="mainheader">

      <a href="https://domain.com/index.php?s1=s1&s2=s2&s3=s3" target="_blank"><img id="topbanner" src="picture.gif"></a>

  </div>
</body>
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Javascript to dynamically create your URL at runtime.  Something like this should work:

```
<a href="#" onclick="RedirectURL();return false;"><img id="topbanner" src="picture.gif"></a>
```

Then in your JS code:

```
function RedirectURL()
{
    var s1 = getUrlVars()["s1"];
    var s2 = getUrlVars()["s2"];
    var s3 = getUrlVars()["s3"];

    var URL = "https://domain.com/index.php?s1=" + s1 + "&s2=" + s2 + "&s3=" + s3;

    window.location = URL;
}

function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it like this..
Give id to your link tag.

```
<a id="myLink" href="#" target="_blank"><img id="topbanner" src="picture.gif"></a>
```

Then you can simply do this.

```
var s1 = getUrlVars()["s1"];
var s2 = getUrlVars()["s2"];
var s3 = getUrlVars()["s3"];
$("a#myLink").attr("href","https://domain.com/index.php?s1=" + s1 + "&s2=" + s2 + "&s3=" + s3);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple ways to do it:

1. If you want to pick and choose which params you want to pass from the current location to new URL, use this approach:

Body:

```
<body>
  <div id="main">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="mainheader">

      <a href="https://domain.com/index.php?" target="_blank"></a><br>
      <a href="https://domain.com/index.php?" target="_blank"></a>

  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function getParams() {
    var params = location.search.substring(1);
    var arrParams = params.split('&');
    var objParams = {};
    for(var i=0; i<arrParams.length; i++) {
        var arrParam = arrParams[i].split("=");
        objParams[arrParam[0]] = arrParam[1];
    }
    return objParams;
}

var objParams = getParams();
var theURL = 'https://domain.com/index.php?s1=' + objParams["s1"] + "&s3=" + objParams["s3"];
$($('a')[0]).attr('href',theURL).attr('title',theURL).html(theURL);
```

2. Otherwise, if you want to just pass all the params, use this:

Body:

```
<body>
  <div id="main">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="mainheader">

      <a href="https://domain.com/index.php?" target="_blank"></a><br>
      <a href="https://domain.com/index.php?" target="_blank"></a>

  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function getParams2() {
    var params = location.search.substring(1);
    return params;
}

var Params = getParams2();
$($('a')[1]).attr('href','https://domain.com/index.php?' + Params).attr('title',$($('a')[1]).attr('href')).html($($('a')[1]).attr('href'));
```

Putting it all together:

```
<body>
  <div id="main">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="mainheader">

      <a href="https://domain.com/index.php?" target="_blank"></a><br>
      <a href="https://domain.com/index.php?" target="_blank"></a>

  </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getParams() {
    var params = location.search.substring(1);
    var arrParams = params.split('&');
    var objParams = {};
    for(var i=0; i<arrParams.length; i++) {
        var arrParam = arrParams[i].split("=");
        objParams[arrParam[0]] = arrParam[1];
    }
    return objParams;
}

var objParams = getParams();
var theURL = 'https://domain.com/index.php?s1=' + objParams["s1"] + "&s3=" + objParams["s3"];
$($('a')[0]).attr('href',theURL).attr('title',theURL).html(theURL);


function getParams2() {
    var params = location.search.substring(1);
    return params;
}

var Params = getParams2();
$($('a')[1]).attr('href','https://domain.com/index.php?' + Params).attr('title',$($('a')[1]).attr('href')).html($($('a')[1]).attr('href'));

</script>
```